# PowerShell 7 using FilterXPath syntax errors

Tags: get-winevent, powershell-7.3

I'm trying to extract some records from the Windows System Log with PowerShell 7 using "get-winevent"

I'm getting different errors depending on the many variations of my command I've run, using various posts as guides.

Note: $tm below is a concatenation of the date and time in UTC (2023-08-11T02:00:00.000Z)

**Command:**

```
PS C:\Users\~salcicct> get-winevent -LogName System -FilterXPath *[System[Provider[@Name='User32' or @Name='Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient'] and (Level=1 or Level=4 or Level=0) and TimeCreated[@SystemTime -ge $tm]]]
```

**Returns:**
Level=1: The term 'Level=1' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Or I get "Get-WinEvent: The specified query is invalid."

If I use single or double quotes for **Level = '1'**, etc. it fails.

And if I take out the whole "level" business, it starts complaining about "and".

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax?

I have tried many variations of the syntax based on different articles/posts to which I have been referring. I am running the command in an elevated shell.